# Draw rich text with QPainter

Tags: qt, qstring, qpainter

is there a way to draw fixed text that has subscripts. My goal is to have something like: "K_max=K_2 . 3"

```
QString equation="K_max=K_2 . 3";
painter.drawText( QRect(x, y , width, y+height), Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignVCenter, equation);
```

I also tried formatting the text using html tags but it didn't help (tags got printed with the text):

```
QString equation="<p>K<sub>max</sub></p>=<p>K<sub>2</sub></p>.3"
```

Comment: You can show it in a QLabel, like: `QLabel lbl("<p>K<sub>max</sub></p>=<p>K<sub>2</sub></p>.3"); lbl.show();`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'am trying to print the text to a pdf file using QPrinter as a paint device

Comment: You can set that html code to a label, than grab the label's content as a pixmap and paint the text as an image with your printer. Otherwise there is no such function that supports drawing formulas.

Comment: Try using unicode. Qt usually work good with it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts

Comment: @vahancho you wrong, there is such function. Check my answer.

Comment: @Amartel thanks. I tried using unicodes and it worked for defined characters but the "m" for example is missing

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is a full example using rich text of QTextDocument.

mainWindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainWindow.h"

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QTextDocument td;
    td.setHtml("K<sub>max</sub>=K<sub>2</sub> &middot; 3");
    td.drawContents(&painter);
}
```

If you need to draw the text at specific point, translate the coordinate system of the painter before drawing:

```
painter.translate(QPointF(50, 50));
```

mainWindow.cpp - Another solution:

```
#include "mainWindow.h"

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QTextDocument td;
    td.setHtml("K<sub>max</sub>=K<sub>2</sub> &middot; 3");
    QAbstractTextDocumentLayout::PaintContext ctx;
    ctx.clip = QRectF( 0, 0, 400, 100 );
    td.documentLayout()->draw( &painter, ctx );
}
```

mainWindow.h:

```
#include <QtGui>

class MainWindow: public QWidget
{
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "mainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

The project file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
QT += gui
HEADERS = mainWindow.h
SOURCES = main.cpp mainWindow.cpp
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You have memory leak in `main`. But thatnks for writing samples to my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it works fine for the position (0, 0), but as soon as I try to move the text to a predefined position in the page ("ctx.clip = QRectF( x, y, 400, 100 );") it disappears! Any ideas how I can fix this ?

Comment: Edited my answer to include this case. In brief, translate with "painter.translate(QPointF(50, 50));".

Comment: If I need to draw at a specific point, isn't there any other way to do that than to translate the `QPainter` object? Maybe I have received a `QPainter` object as a function argument but have declared the argument `const`; then I won't be able to translate it. (A `QPainter` object cannot be copied either.)

Comment: Any way to translate with a specific base line. For example I want my base line to be at (10,50), but translating it to (10,50) renders the text at (14,75). I now have trouble aligning text drawn with drawText.

Answer (score 6):

You may use supported [Qt HTML subset](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) to format your text. If you need to draw formatted text, you should use [`QTextDocument::drawContents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#drawContents).

`QPainter::drawText` is designed for plain text without formatting, and it works much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Since Qt 4.7, you can use [`QPainter.drawStaticText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt/qpainter.html#drawStaticText) with [`QStaticText`](https://doc.qt.io/qt/qstatictext.html):

```py
painter = QPainter()
top_left = QPoint(0, 0)
painter.drawStaticText(top_left, QStaticText('foo<b>bar</b>'))
```

> `QStaticText` will attempt to guess the format of the input text using `Qt::mightBeRichText()`, and interpret it as rich text if this function returns `true`.

If the limitations of `QStaticText` suit you (see class description), it should be much faster than `QTextDocument`.