# QFont doens't allow line spacing or leading to be set manually

Tags: c++, qt, fonts, spacing, fontmetrics

I've been trying to find a way to change a font file's line spacing default value, using `QFont`, `QFontMetrics` or something like that. I'm using `QPainter::drawText` to draw some text in a bounding rectangle.

It's strange that `QFont` allows for font kerning to be changed and even has some stretch operation and letter spacing but nothing to change the default space between lines. I've searched and found some partial solutions using `QTextLayout` but none seemed to work properly.

I need to use `QPainter` because I generate a texture with the text to be rendered with OpenGL.

Looking for more ideas for me to try out!

**UPDATE**

I've found that I can use `QPainter` to draw a `QStaticText` which allows for HTML text formatting, similar to `QTextDocument`. However, CSS styling doesn't work like in `QTextDocument` (there's a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-25420))... Therefore still no leading but I hope this puts me on the right track.

**SOLVED**

I got what I wanted using `QTextDocument`, like Mykhaylo suggested. [Link to solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892203/draw-rich-text-with-qpainter/29894245#29894245)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QFontMetrics` was not designed particularly for multi-line text.

Use `QTextDocument`. You can print multi-line and rich text with it, even using `QPainter`. See the solution how to [use QPainter with QTextDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892203/draw-rich-text-with-qpainter/29894245#29894245)

Comment: It works like intended. Really awesome Mykhaylo :). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is not much that can be done here.

[`QFontMetrics::lineSpacing`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#lineSpacing) returns what you need but it is read-only.

It's the sum of font height and leading. You can adjust height - set it in `QFont` constructor. But you can't set leading.

Some people add `\n` to the end of string to increase space between lines but of course this is not always a good solution.

Comment: Thank you for the quick awnser @demonplus. I'll check the QFont documentation and see if what you suggested solves my problem. I'll post back the results :)

Comment: I can't to find any QFont constructor which takes a height parameter... adding new line characters will mess the word wrap so that isn't a solution for me either. But thanks again for your time @demonplus ;)

Comment: QFont::QFont(const QString & family, int pointSize = -1, int weight = -1, bool italic = false) - when you will change pointSize, height of the font will change also

Comment: I got confused with what you meant with height ^^. Line spacing will change with height but leading will stay the same :). So no solution still.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I tried to describe it in my answer. Qt allows to change height of font but you can't change leading.