# Is there a way to change just part painted text

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

Let's say I have painted 2 words:

```
qp.setFont(self.font)
qp.setPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
qp.drawText(event.rect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, str(self.setText + '\nKm/h'))
```

and have loaded custom font, is there a way to change font size just `self.Text` and `'\nKm/k'` leave at it is?

EDIT: I come up with to draw another text with different size.

Comment: self.setText ??

Comment: explain your question, please

Comment: as you can see there is self.setText (= 000) + 'Km/h' to draw and my question is there a way to set font size just for self.setText. I hope you got this :)

Comment: just draw it as two separated text

Comment: @furas yes I did, but can I do without drawing another text?

Comment: you could use `HTML` but it may need more work to style this text (and can be slower): [Draw rich text with QPainter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29892203/draw-rich-text-with-qpainter)

Comment: self.setText({text}) is used to place a text, it does not return anything, so I find it incoherent in your code, it would be more coherent self.text ()

Comment: thanks guys! I thinks I will stick with draw another text.